# Enable or disable a TextBox depending on the selected ComboBoxItem

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a Combobox and some text Boxes, I want to disable some text boxes deppending on the selected item in the ComboBox.
the Xaml code:

```
<ComboBox Name="Combo" ItemsSource="{Binding ModeReglementList}"}"/>
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Combo, .........}"/>
```

What is the simplest way to accomplish this dependency control in WPF?

Comment: Or a converter in a binding, or a data trigger in a style.

Comment: @EldHasp how to accomplish this with a Data trigger ? i'm new in xaml.

Comment: Describe the conditions for IsEnabled to depend on the value of the item selected in the ComboBox.

Comment: @EldHasp Can you post an answer please?

Comment: I can. But for an example, I need you to describe the conditions that need to be implemented in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a `Style` with data triggers to the `TextBox`.

In the below markup, the `TextBox` will be disabled when you select "b" in the `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox Name="Combo" ItemsSource="{Binding ModeReglementList}" />

<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=Combo}" Value="b">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

**View Model**:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ModeReglementList { get; } =
    new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
```

You can add other triggers to trigger on different values.